# Explain this Uncaught TypeError: Property 'x' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: javascript, scope

Can someone please explain why I get the results I do in each of the following situations? I wish to understand why the outcomes are what they are regarding how JavaScript works with scope, if this is what the issue is. In the first example, my code functions properly.

```
var Employees = function(name, salary) {
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;

    this.addSalary = addSalaryFunction;

    this.getSalary = function() {
        return this.salary;
    };

};

var addSalaryFunction = function(addition) {
        this.salary = this.salary + addition;
    };


var ceo = new Employees("Chris", 400000);
ceo.addSalary(20000);
document.write(ceo.getSalary());
```

If I move the `addSalaryFunction` into the `Employees` function, and below `this.addSalary` I get the Uncaught TypeError.

```
var Employees = function(name, salary) {
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;

    this.addSalary = addSalaryFunction;

    this.getSalary = function() {
        return this.salary;
    };

    var addSalaryFunction = function(addition) {
        this.salary = this.salary + addition;
    };
};

var ceo = new Employees("Chris", 400000);
ceo.addSalary(20000);
document.write(ceo.getSalary());
```

But if I move the `addSalaryFunction` above `this.addSalary` if works properly again. Although my IDE tells me that my local variable `addSalaryFunction` is redundant.

```
var Employees = function(name, salary) {
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;

    var addSalaryFunction = function(addition) {
        this.salary = this.salary + addition;
    };

    this.addSalary = addSalaryFunction;

    this.getSalary = function() {
        return this.salary;
    };

};


var ceo = new Employees("Chris", 400000);
ceo.addSalary(20000);
document.write(ceo.getSalary());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you're trying to assign the function before it was created.

```
this.addSalary = addSalaryFunction; // there's no function yet

//...

var addSalaryFunction = function(addition) {  // now there is, but too late
    this.salary = this.salary + addition;
};
```

---

When you moved the variable assignment above the `this.addSalary = addSalaryFunction`, you're now creating the function before trying to reference it.

```
var addSalaryFunction = function(addition) {  // here's the function
    this.salary = this.salary + addition;
};
this.addSalary = addSalaryFunction;  // now we can assign it
```

---

If you had used function declaration syntax instead, the first version would work, because the function declarations are "hoisted" *(as they say)* to the top of the variable scope.

```
this.addSalary = addSalaryFunction; // This now works because of the magic below

//...

// This is magically hoisted to the top
function addSalaryFunction(addition) {
    this.salary = this.salary + addition;
}
```

Comment: [Great explanation here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/)

Comment: @chris_s: You're welcome. Ultimately, the cleanest solution is to use what ***rGil*** posted. But IMO, even better is to use prototypal inheritance by putting all your methods on `Employees.prototype`. Then they're shared between all Employee objects instead of recreated for every object.

Answer (score 2):

Second method does not work because addSalaryFunction is being referenced before it has been declared.

You could eliminate some code and just declare:

```
this.addSalary = function(addition) {
    this.salary = this.salary + addition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a much simpler form:

```
var foo = function() {
    var x = y;
    var y = 2;
    return x;
};

var bar = function() {
    var y = 2;
    var x = y;
    return x;
};
```

Obviously, `bar()` will return 2. `foo`, however, gets `undefined` when it looks for a value of `y` on the first line, so returns `undefined`. While variable *declarations* are hoisted to the top of their scope, variable *initialisations* are not.

Answer (score 0):

It's a specific hoisting problem. Have a look at this explanation: http://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-hoisting/